# Redirecting function definitions in python

Tags: python, class-attributes

This is a very contrived example as it's not easy to explain the context in which I have ended up implementing this solution. However, if anyone can answer why this particular peculiarity happens, I'd be grateful.

The example:

```
class A(dict):  
    def __init__(self):
        self['a'] = 'success'

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        print 'getitem'
        return dict.__getitem__(name)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()
        setattr(self, '__getitem__', self._a.__getitem__) 

b = B()
c = b['a']
```

This outputs:

```
c = b['a']
TypeError: 'B' object is unsubscriptable
```

Even though it's a bizarre way of doing this (clearly subclassing would be more logical), why doesn't it find the method I have explicitly set?

If I do this:

```
dir(b)
```

I get this:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__weakref__', '_a']
```

The same issue occurs with other methods such as `__iter__`. What is it about explicitly defining this method that works?

Comment: Hint: if it's not easy to explain, it's not a good idea.  Try describing your goal instead of a contrived route to the goal.  Someone might be able to give you something that is less contrived.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I'll post a question about the actual problem I'm solving and let you figure out what you think the best way of handling this is.

Comment: Dan: Can you post a link for people who have arrived at this question and are curious what the context was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use brackets *`[]`* python looks in the class. You must set the method in the class.

Here's your code adapted:

```
class A(dict):  
    def __init__(self):
        self['a'] = 'success'

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        print 'getitem!'
        return dict.__getitem__(self, name)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = A()
        B.__getitem__ = self._a.__getitem__

b = B()
c = b['a']
```

Comment: Hang on, you're pointing a class method to an instance method, doesn't that mean it'll point to the same instance for all instances of B?

Comment: @Dan: yes. __getitem__ only works for the entire class. There is no per-instance __getitem__.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't override special class methods on the fly.

I wasn't able to find a reference about this but is basically because they are class methods and are not allowed to be instance methods.

Comment: you can override them on the fly, the mistake was that Dan messed with instance methods instead of class methods.

Comment: spot on, I didn't understand the difference between instance methods and class methods in this sense. thanks.